# Use custom Hibernate User Type on google app engine

Tags: hibernate, google-app-engine, usertype

I've been struggling with this for a while, but I can't seem to find any valid explanation for it.

I'm developing some application which contains a User-class.  This User-class has an attribute e-mail, which is of type EmailAddress.  This class contains some business logic and first was immutable.  I created a custom user type (Hibernate) to handle the persistence of the EmailAddress-class.  However, GAE doesn't like it.  When I deploy my application and test it (or run it locally on my machine), that field is always null.  However, yesterday evening I tested on a local MySQL installation with no reference to GAE whatsoever and it works fine.

If I check the log files, I don't see any errors or warnings.  The application starts fine.

Is there anyone who can tell me whether or not this is normal?  It seems weird to me that GAE doesn't allow this kind of Hibernate-behaviour, but maybe there's a valid reason.  If you want, I can give you a sample application which can be deployed on a Tomcat and GAE.

Comment: Why would GAE support Hibernate-specific stuff, since it doesn't use Hibernate as JPA engine, and doesn't even use a SQL database as storage engine?

Comment: Any alternative to do this?

Comment: Hi did you manage to find a solution to this in the end?